# Get all information schema from Database tables

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

How can I limit the following query to return for only tables in the database and exclude views?

```
USE [Database Name] SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: I would use sys.tables and join to sys.columns and not use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views at all. I am not alone in thinking these views are not all they are cracked up to be. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft discourages the use of INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The way to do it if you don't want to use the sys views:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
        ON  T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE       T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Join it to sys.Tables:

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c inner join sys.tables t
        on c.Table_Name = t.name
```